# PDO query returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to execute a query one is working and one isn't

Code:

```
    $sth = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `service_id` = :service AND `created` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 1, :limit");
    $leng = $this->_settings->length;
    $sth->bindParam(":service", $this->_settings->service, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(":limit", $leng, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $component_data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    var_dump($component_data);
```

echo values : `SELECT * FROM`messages`WHERE`service_id`= 3 AND`created`> (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 1, 5` this query isn't working

and this one is: `SELECT * FROM`messages`WHERE`service_id`= 2 AND`created`> (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 1, 5`

If I execute the first one inside my database editor tool I get this as result:

[image: result]

Why isn't the first query returning anything? and why is the second query returning something? even though they're the same?

Comment: Note that **`LIMIT 1,n`** is "skipping" the first row returned; if you don't want to skip that row, you'd use either **`LIMIT 0,n`** or just **`LIMIT n`**.

Comment: @spencer7593 I know but I'm skipping the first row for various reasons but if you look at my example the not working query is still returning something.

Comment: The last sentence in the question doesn't make much sense. "first" and "first"

Comment: @Chuck Whoops sorry edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not spotting any specific error.

But the first suspect on the list is the `bindParam`. For debugging, I'd try using a scalar, and also echo out the value.

```
$service_param = $this->_settings->service;
var_dump($service_param); 
$sth->bindParam(":service", $this->_settings->service, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

For debugging, I'd also try removing the bind placeholder for LIMIT, and hardcoding that in the statement.

---

Since there's no check of the return from the "prepare" and "execute" functions, so I'm going to assume that the PDO error mode is set to throw an exception if a database error occurs. That is, I'm assuming that the database connection has these attributes set:

```
$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but somehow the error was because $this->_settings->service was returning "2" instead of 2

Comment: Since your answer explains alot to me I'll set yours as the accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I spot various mistakes.

1: (deleted ignore)

2: Your limit clause should be 0,something. Putting a 1 there makes it skip 1 record.

Comment: I'm sorry but both your statements are wrong. I want to skip the first record + if I remove the pdo::FETHC_OBJ I get a half bugged triple array

Comment: Whats the output if you omit the FETCH_OBJ?

Comment: Just a normal array but every key was duplicated But I fixed it I had an error inside another part of my code. Apperantly still don't know why that bugged my query.

Comment: AH the :service was a string instead of int so it bugged the query.